# Jmeter - How to Check against empty DB query

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test, i need to check if the query is returning empty data (nothing), then enter into another condition accordingly.

My test looks like:

1. execute db query
   [image]
2. If DB, does not provides anything (empty data), then enter into the If condition.

[image]

[image]

What is the easiest way to archive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SQL query returns nothing the JDBC Request sampler will generate the following JMeter Variable:

```
resultSet_#=0
```

you can observe it yourself using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

[image]

If you want to run some logic when the query doesn't return the results add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) after the JDBC Request sampler and use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

```
${__jexl3(${resultSet_#} == 0,)}
```

[image]

If everything goes well If Controller's children will be executed only when the query returns empty result set:

[image]